# Commits count in local branch after Git rebase

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm trying out Git rebase in my test project so as to learn how it works. May be I'm missing something trivial, but i'm not able to figure out how the commits count got the value it shows in the log.

I have 2 branches. Master and Dev. There are no pending commits in any branch, that are to be pushed to the remote branches.
And this is how it looks before rebase:
[image: Before Rebase]
And now i do the rebase using the below set of commands:

```
C:\GitRepositories\boney_git_fun>git checkout dev

C:\GitRepositories\boney_git_fun>git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: dev commit 2
Applying: dev commit 3    

C:\GitRepositories\boney_git_fun>git status
On branch dev
Your branch and 'origin/dev' have diverged,
and have 6 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

C:\GitRepositories\boney_git_fun>git push --force
```

Ok. I have pushed the changes to the remote repository and this is how it looks now.
[image: After Rebase]

And now my question. In the log below,

> C:\GitRepositories\boney_git_fun>git status
>       On branch dev
>       Your **branch and 'origin/dev'** have diverged,
>       and have **6 and 2 different commits** each, respectively.

how did the local dev branch have 6 commits after rebase ? I could think only of 4 commits in the local dev branch, which are:

1. master commit 4
2. master commit 5
3. dev commit 2(the new commit created on top of rebased master)
4. dev commit 3(the new commit created on top of rebased master)

Could anyone please tell me about the missing 2 commits? Let me know if any more info is required.

Comment: Your branch diagrams are very hard to read, and you would have done better to include them as text, formatted as code.

Comment: This is complicated, because you have a merge commit in there, but long story short what happened is that you rewound your `dev` branch, brought in a bunch of commits from `master`, then reapplied the `dev` commits from the point where the two branches diverged.  This is why you are getting 6/2 for the divergence stats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to realize that some commits are on *many* branches.  When you did the rebase, you changed the label `dev`.  Four existing commits that *were*, earlier, only on `master` are now on both `master` *and* `dev`.  Two other commits that were on `dev` are no longer on `dev` at all; instead, *new* commits—replacements for the two old ones; *copies*—are now on `dev`.

Here are the two chains of commits (before and after, transcribed from your images) along with their hash IDs.<sup>1</sup>  I have also added the branch labels.  Note that a commit's hash ID is its "true name": this is the real identity of the commit.  It's shortlog, e.g., `master commit 4`, is just a text string that can be copied to a new and different commit.  In other words, those gobbledygook strings of hexadecimal characters `c4ef678` and so on are the actual names to which you should pay attention.

---

<sup>1</sup>This graph is *not* drawn the way `git log --graph --oneline` would draw it, it's a literal transcription of your images.  The `--graph` option turns on topological sorting in `git log`, which changes how the commits are clustered in the one-per-line output, and also attempts to draw first and second parents of merges in a particular way, neither of which is the case here.

---

**before:**

```
*    c4ef678  dev commit 3      (dev)
| *  6d98d13  master commit 5   (master)
| *  531ae4f  master commit 4
* |  1d1165d  dev commit 2
| *  264c713  Merged dev into master
|/|
| *  d3145f2  master commit 3
* |  e855864  dev commit 1
|/
*    e90a213  master commit 2
*    abe2416  master branch commit
*    6685b20  README.md created online with Bitbucket
```

Note that commits `c4ef678` and `1d1165d` are *only* on `dev`; commits `6d98d13` and `531ae4f` and `264c713` and `d3145f2` are *only* on `master`; and `e855864` and below are on *both* branches.  To see this, start at the commit that bears the branch name label—`c4ef678` for `dev`, or `6d98d13` for `master`—and follow the connecting lines from dot to dot (asterisk to asterisk in the text copies here).  You can only move in the generally-downward direction, but at a merge like `264c713`, follow *both* lines downward.

**after:**

```
*    e09e49b  dev commit 3     (dev)
*    6a8c956  dev commit 2
*    6d98d13  master commit 5  (master)
*    531ae4f  master commit 4
*    264c713  Merged dev into master
|\
* |  d3145f2  master commit 3
| *  e855864  dev commit 1
|/
*    e90a213  master commit 2
*    abe2416  master branch commit
*    6685b20  README.md created online with Bitbucket
```

This graph is much simpler to follow: commit `e09e49b` is the *tip* of `dev`, and it and its predecessor `6a8c956` are *only* on `dev`.  After—well, *before*, really ... before those, we have `6d98d13`, which is the *tip* of `master` and is on both `master` *and* `dev`.  Then we have `531ae4f`, which is likewise on both `master` and `dev`, and so on.

We can see, now, that what `git rebase` did was to *copy* original commits `c4ef678` and `1d1165d` to *new* commits `e09e49b` and `6a8c956` respectively.  The parent of `6a8c956` is `6d98d13`, which is the tip of `master`.  The parent of `c4ef678` is of course `1d1165d`—which means the copying happened in the reverse order, i.e., the older commit got copied first, then the newer one: "forward" order in Git is actually backwards, as Git starts with the *tip-most* commit as identified by a branch label, then moves back through previous commits by looking at each commit's parent.  For a merge commit, which is distinguished by having two parents,<sup>2</sup> Git looks at *both* parents.

Since commits can be on more than one branch at a time, the act of copying the two `dev`-only commits to two new commits that sit atop the existing commits that *were*, before, only on `master`, has now changed things so that there are *six* commits on `dev` that were not on `dev` before: the copied two, and the four that had been only on `master`.  These are the six that are reported here:

> ```
> Your branch and 'origin/dev' have diverged, and
> have 6 and 2 different commits each, respectively
> ```

The two that are only on `origin/dev`—this is also your own label, in *your* repository; it's your repository's memory of what is or was on `origin`—are the original two before the copying.  That is, if we drew them in, we'd have this slightly more complicated graph:

```
*      c4ef678  dev commit 3     (origin/dev)
*      1d1165d  dev commit 2
| *    e09e49b  dev commit 3     (dev)
| *    6a8c956  dev commit 2
| *    6d98d13  master commit 5  (master)
| *    531ae4f  master commit 4
| *    264c713  Merged dev into master
| |\
| | *  d3145f2  master commit 3
|/  |
*   |  e855864  dev commit 1
|  /
| /
|/
*      e90a213  master commit 2
*      abe2416  master branch commit
*      6685b20  README.md created online with Bitbucket
```

If you scan the connecting lines here, you can see which commits are the six on `dev` that are not on `origin/dev`, and which are the two that are on `origin/dev` that are not on `dev`.

---

<sup>2</sup>A merge commit is actually any commit with two *or more* parents, but the "or more" case is a bit odd.  These commits are called *octopus merges* and octopus merges are never actually *required*, so they are mostly for showing off. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed answer. Helped me a lot. It took me a lot of time and re-reads to get a grasp of it. I can imagine the effort you put for creating the branch diagrams and the beautiful explanation to go with it. 

And apologies from my end for not putting the branch diagram in the way you put in the answer. Reason is that, I was thinking someone would answer by just stating those particular commit names and the reason for those commits.

But you blew me away with your answer. Thank you again !!